# Retiming a data.table in long format

Tags: r, date, join, data.table

I need to resample the following table x given the dates in table y, but I would like to keep the dates that do not match for each ID in the table. Easier to explain with this simple example (I am using data.table and lubridate libraries):

```
x <- data.table(id = c("A","A","A","B","B"), date = dmy(c("01-01-2010","01-01-2012","01-01-2014","01-01-2010","01-01-2012")),
                v1 =1:5)
x
   id       date v1
1:  A 2010-01-01  1
2:  A 2012-01-01  2
3:  A 2014-01-01  3
4:  B 2010-01-01  4
5:  B 2012-01-01  5

y <- data.table(date = dmy(c("01-01-2010","01-01-2013")) )

y
         date
1: 2010-01-01
2: 2013-01-01
```

This is the output that I need:

```
   id       date v1
1:  A 2010-01-01  1
2:  A 2013-01-01 NA
3:  B 2010-01-01  4
4:  B 2013-01-01 NA
```

One solution I found, which is easy for this small example, is to create a "long format" version of b that includes the IDs as follows

```
y <- data.table(id = c("A","A","B","B"), date = dmy(c("01-01-2010","01-01-2013","01-01-2010","01-01-2013")) )

y
   id       date
1:  A 2010-01-01
2:  A 2013-01-01
3:  B 2010-01-01
4:  B 2013-01-01
```

Then set two keys

```
setkey(x,id,date)
setkey(y,id,date)
```

Then finally do a right join

```
x[y]
```

This gives me the result I want in this simple, small example. However, in my real-life case my table x has many millions of rows (this is one-minute-frequency data), whereas table y (the resampling dates) is only few hundreds rows. I guess it is needlessly too memory consuming to create a new y that is also millions of rows long to do the trick.
As an alternative, I thought I could do a for loop and split the data table in chunks according to the ID at every loop, then do the right join on the original y (but setting only one key). However, I would like to avoid the loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option:

```
x[CJ(id, date=y$date, unique=TRUE), on=.NATURAL]
```

Comment: Many thanks! This seems to work nicely. Perhaps oddly (?) it does not seem much faster than a loop when applied to my dataset (more than 100 million rows for 6 variables), but at least it is much more elegant.